# Set active link on page using includes

Tags: php, html

I have written some code that will highlight a link in the header based on: `class="active"`. The class is connected to some CSS code to style it.

I am currently adding the `class="active"` the specified link for each page. However, since I want to move my header into it's own file and include it on each page, I will lose the ability to set the class for each page. I could of course add a variable that will allow me to sort of do the same thing.

What I wish to know is if there is a better and secure way to automatically set the `class="active"` to the page that I am on. I have seen some posts that suggest using: `($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but I have read that it could cause some security issues.

Lastly the main problem that I have is that I need to set two links to 
`class="active"` if I am viewing a page that is in the portfolio list item. For instance, if games.html is currently viewed, both the games and the portfolio page should have the code: `class="active"`.

*(All of my .html files are read as .php)*
Here is the html code I have so far:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="games.html">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="2d-art.html">2D Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="3d-models.html">3D Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="particles.html">Particles</a></li>
            <li><a href="shaders.html">Shaders</a></li>
            <li><a href="environments.html">Environments</a></li>
            <li><a href="programming.html">Programming</a></li>
            <li><a href="substance-designer.html">Substance Designer</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/store.html">Store</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP_SELF` is safe when you only use it to compare values and don't directly use it in your html:

The portfolio menu can be made active by nested all related pages in a folder called `portfolio` and checking if the path starts with that folder.

```
<?php
$currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$portfolioFolder = 'portfolio/';

$isPortfolioFolder = substr($currentPage, 0, strlen($portfolioFolder)) == $portfolioFolder);
?>

<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="<?= $isPortfolioPage ? 'active' : '' ?>" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="games.html" class="<?= $currentPage === 'games.html' ? 'active' : '' ?>">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="2d-art.html" class="<?= $currentPage === '2d-art.html' ? 'active' : '' ?>">2D Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="3d-models.html">3D Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="particles.html">Particles</a></li>
            <li><a href="shaders.html">Shaders</a></li>
            <li><a href="environments.html">Environments</a></li>
            <li><a href="programming.html">Programming</a></li>
            <li><a href="substance-designer.html">Substance Designer</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/store.html">Store</a></li>
</ul>
```